# Correct file path to image file

Tags: html, css, image

I've been unable to get an image to show up and I think it's due to incorrect file linking but I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm uploading images directly onto Cloud9 into a folder called "images." The folder is nested in a folder called "jobquiz"

I'm trying to include the image on my homepage. These are the ways I've tried to link the image but every time I get a "cannot be found" error. Can someone help me correct my file path? Thanks!

The image is called "guy.jpeg"

I've tried the following:

```
<img src="images/guy.jpeg" alt="">
<img src="/images/guy.jpeg" alt="">
<img src="./images/guy.jpeg" alt="">
<img src="../images/guy.jpeg" alt="">
<img src="jobquiz/images/guy.jpeg" alt="">
<img src="/jobquiz/images/guy.jpeg" alt="">
```

[image]

Comment: We'd have to see your file structure

Comment: I think I explained it above

Comment: where is your homepage located?

Comment: Not enough for me :D Could you take a screenshot of the file system, including the image and the html file you're trying to display the image in

Comment: Text casing is important .JPG is not the same as jpg....for instance...and jpeg is not the same as jpg.

Comment: Tell us your directory structure, if not, we have not a crystal ball to adivine that. You are explained that you are uploading an image to Cloud9. I don't know what is Cloud9. You must to explain your case and add the details to help you. If not, we can't help you

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude he doesn't need to explain what Cloud9 is -_- That's something you can easily get with a google search

Comment: :) Uploading image...

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi try `../../images/guy.jpeg`. However, I think it's probably that the problem is your views are being compiled to another location, and you'll need to find the path to the image from there(or the web root)

Comment: @JacobGray maybe you don't know the stackoverflow rules to make a question. It's something that you can easily get with a google search. I didn't said that I need to know what Cloud9 is, I only give an example to tell OP that his question is poor, and he assumed that we know things that he knows, but we don't.

Comment: Gosh still didn't work. I'm shocked this is so complicated. Usually I upload images to a file sharing service but Its unreliable thus I'm trying to switch to hosting them directly on my website. Any advise?

Comment: In what URL are you seeing the result page? This is important, because you need to include the path depending on the URL you are seeing, not exactly since where your file is in the folder structure.

Comment: Heres the error:

https://jobquiz-andrewleonardi.c9users.io/images/guy.jpeg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are you sure that `images` folder is public accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Without you sharing your exact file structure from your HTML to your image location we cannot help you other than explain that placing two dots and a slash from your path tells the browser to go to the parent folder and then to execute the path you provided (ex. "../images/guy.jpeg") and this can be done multiple times on a path. Here is an good example of what I'm trying to say - https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Another thing you can do is to use the base tag in your HTML. To use the base tag, just place `<base href="http://www.yourrooturl.com" />` just under your title tag in your HTML head and then just point your image like `<img src="images/guy.jpeg" alt="">` as long as the images folder is in an immediate child of the root folder of your website.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
I saw your image, you can try using a base tag, or you can also try `<img src="../../images/guy.jpeg" alt="">` for your image path.

Comment: Thanks for trying! Amazingly <img src="../../images/guy.jpeg" alt=""> still isnt working. I'm stuck!

Comment: If your images folder is within the root of the page, try using the base tag. Also, looking at your screenshot, I noticed that you are building a node app with express, have you tried using a dynamically generated URL instead of relying on HTML's routing?

Comment: Hm. No such luck. Maybe it just cannot be done this way. Which seems impossible but you never know. 

Hmm I'll have to look into that!